# Assigning new values to an unbound box in my report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have designed a Report from a query.

It is important for me that the fully written out names of babies appear in a specific unbounded box in my report, i.e. where names start with "ETA*" please write out "Etanerella", for example.

When I run the code I don't got any warning, but nothing is being written in my unbounded box.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Sub testing()
' Defining the rename baby names

Dim newBio As String
Dim sqlANA  As String
Dim sqlADA  As String
Dim sqlCAN  As String
Dim sqlETA  As String

    sqlANA = "Alice"
    sqlABA = "About"
    sqlCAN = "Canibal"
    sqlETA = "Etanerella"   

    'newBio = Left(Me![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1], 3)

    If Left(Reports![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1], 3) Like "*ETA*" Then
        'Me!BIOnew.OptionValue = sqlETA

    ElseIf Reports![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1] Like "*ADA*" Then
        'Me!BIOnew.OptionValue = sqlADA

    ElseIf Reports![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1] Like "*ANA*" Then
        'Me!BIOnew.OptionValue = sqlADA

    Else
        Reports!BIOnew.OptionValue = "baba"

    End If
    'the code
End Sub
```

Comment: How and when are you running this code? Is the report already open? In which view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *Value* property for a textbox:

```
If Left(Reports![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1], 3) = "ETA" Then
    Me!BIOnew.Value = sqlETA
```

Comment: Then you are left with debugging your values. "did not work" adds no clue.

Answer (score 0):

What is [tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1]? Is it your report name. The whole report can't equal a string value. You need to put your object name as well.

```
If Left(Reports![tbl_PatientJADAS_B1.Therapie1]!MyUnboundedTextBox, 3 Like "*ETA*" Then Me!BIOnew.Value = sqlETA
```

Your statements after your first 3 'if's are commented out so won't do anything right now.

Some other things to try:
Is your unbounded box big enough (width and height)?
Is it using the same color font as the background color?